# Buying a SIM card on arrival in Amsterdam

Tags: cellphones, amsterdam

I will land at Amsterdam airport on 8th November. Are there shops selling prepaid SIM cards there? How much time does it take for a SIM to get activated? Any recommendations? I would like a plan with about 100MB data usage and 1 hour each of local and international calls.

Comment: Where are you from? These days European Roaming packages from your own provider can be the cheapest option

Comment: @andra India. Sure, let me check.

Answer (score 4):

I landed at Schiphol yesterday evening (around 21:00). I saw a Lebara stand in the plaza hall where you can get free sim and activate it. You can find the prices [here](http://www.lebara.nl/). I used for a while Lebara mobile and quality of calls was reasonable.

Comment: yup, and there are a few more shops selling cellphones and cards in the area, including past arrivals in the mall.

Comment: Is that 4G or 3G? I couldn't find that on their website.

Comment: I just asked support and they told that it is 3G connection

Comment: I just bought a Lebara SIM for 30 euro, consisting of 15 euro airtime and 1G data. The Lebara stand is at arrivals 3 in the Schiphol plaza, at the Body Shop (shop 13).